# join in update command in trigger

Tags: mysql, join, triggers, sql-update

I have 3 tables, tbl_image, tbl_vehicle_image and tbl_vehicle

tbl_vehicle_image resolves a many-many relationship between tbl_image and tbl_vehicle

tbl_vehicle has a last_modified_date

How do I create a trigger that, when I change for example tbl_image.img_lnk, uses tbl_vehicle_image to find all records in tbl_vehicle that use that image, and set their last_modified_date to NOW()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
DELIMITER $$;

create TRIGGER UpdateLastmodifiedDate AFTER UPDATE ON tbl_image
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   UPDATE tbl_vehicle v
   INNER JOIN tbl_vehicle_image vi ON v.vehicleId = vi.vehicleID
   INNER JOIN tbl_image i ON vi.imageid = i.id
   SET v.lastmodified_date = NOW()
   WHERE i.img_lnk = NEW.img_lnk;
END$$
```

Comment: I'll post hers since it's discussing this answer, I added DELIMITER $$ at the top and put a semicolon on the last line (WHERE i.....) and the syntax problems are gone

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trig_after_image_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `tbl_image`
 FOR EACH ROW 
    if old.img_lnk<>NEW.img_lnk
    then
        update tbl_vehicle  set last_modified_date=NOW() where id in (select vehicle_id from tbl_vehicle_image where image_id=OLD.id);
    end if;
```

I don't have all field name of your table so change those. I have used id as primary key for corresponding table.

Comment: for both of these answers I'm getting 'syntax error, unexpected end'

Comment: @KellyLarsen - Try `END$$` instead of `END`.

Comment: @KellyLarsen  Use `set delimiter $$`in starting line.

Comment: I get 'syntax error, unexpected IDENT_QUOTED, expecting EQ or SET_VAR' under the $$ in set delimiter $$

Comment: use this in starting `DELIMITER $$` instead of first one.